# WebApi metadata - ODataModelBuilder not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've found some samples that are using ODataModelBuilder
What NuGetPackage should be referenced ? Seems Microsoft.Data.OData does not contains this class anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package:
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="0.2.0-alpha"

Answer (score -1):

Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData nuget package

Go through this blog post.
http://dilanarandara.blogspot.com/2013/02/odata-using-aspnet-web-api.html